# I need get just two decimal numbers, but seems that toFixed() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to cut my **result** variable in two decimal numbers, but anything work. Even using the Number() function, because it seems that the **price** variable is a string. But nothing work. In some inputs, be show huge amount of decimals:

[image]

This is my code:

```
_renderCoin() {
        console.log(this.state.bpi); 
        const { input } = this.state;       
        const { bpi } = this.state;

        return Object.keys(bpi)
            .map(coin => {
                const price = bpi[coin].rate_float;
                // console.log(price);
                // console.log(typeof price);
                const result = Number(price.toFixed(2));
                console.log(typeof result);

                // const pi = Math.PI;
                // const a = pi.toFixed(4)
                // console.log(a);


                if (coin === 'USD'){
                    return (
                        <div className={styles.info} key={coin}>
                            <hr/>
                            <strong>{input}</strong> BTC is: <strong>U$S      
                                                    {input * result</strong>

                        <span className={styles.money}>{coin}</span>
                    </div>
                )  
            } else {
                return (
                    <div className={styles.info} key={coin}>
                        <strong>{input}</strong> BTC is: <strong>$ 
                                                       {input*result</strong>
                        <span className={styles.money}>{coin}</span>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        })

}

    _handleChange(event){
        this.setState({
            input: event.target.value
        })
    }
```

Comment: `Number(price).toFixed(2);`

Comment: A number in JS is always an IEEE754 double. It doesn't hold a rendering precision

Comment: Uh, don't cast it back to a number after doing `toFixed`? You must use `U$S {(input * result).toFixed(2)}` in the **output**

Comment: I use: `Number.parseFloat(price).toFixed(2)`

Comment: Does your string contain any other characters besides numerical ones and `.`?

Comment: What is `input`? Try `Number((price*Number(input)).toFixed(2))`

Comment: Bergi is work! Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the calculation after the rounding. Instead, you need to call `toFixed` at the point where you output the result as a string:

```
const price = bpi[coin].rate_float;
const result = input * price; // do the calculation here!
console.log(typeof result); // still a number

const denom = coin === 'USD' ? 'US$' : '$';
return (<div className={styles.info} key={coin}>
    <hr/>
    <strong>{input}</strong> BTC is: <strong>{denom}{result.toFixed(2)}</strong>
//                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
    <span className={styles.money}>{coin}</span>
</div>);
```